# Can setTimeout and setInterval have repeating id's?

Tags: javascript

*The following questions apply to both setTimeout and setInterval even though I specifically use setTimeout*

If I have the following

```
var foo = setTimeout(function() {}, 1000);
// foo got timeout id 1234
```

**Question:** After the foo timeout fires can the timeout id 1234 ever be created again by calling setTimeout (without refreshing the page)?

Next lets say I have this:

```
var foo = setTimeout(function() {}, 1000);
// foo got timeout id 1234
clearTimeout(foo);
```

**Question:** If I `clearTimeout(foo)` can 1234 ever be created again by calling setTimeout (without refreshing the page)?

Comment: Of course, it appears as if the id consistently increases but it'd be nice to have a solid answer to ensure that no scenarios can reset the id or if it can round robin and start over from 0.

Comment: It would be a really shity algorithm if the IDs repeated, so I'm going to be an optimist here and say that they're always unique.

Comment: well the `id` returned is a `long` so if it did do a round robin it would probably do it when the id reached the max size of `long` which is quite large http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers

Comment: It's defined in the "timer initialization steps" in the [HTML spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timer-initialization-steps). Read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its going to repeat eventually, there are finite numbers available, there's a limit to unique values. Having said that, there are 9007199254740992 numbers, twice that if you count negative values, so it'll take a while.

Comment: the question is, can they repeat before then?